# How to update a nested sub array in nodejs, mongodb api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a Nodejs/Express and MongoDb backend API for students records and I need help on how to update a sub-field in the data. I have the code below in a Student.js file located in my model directory at root.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const StudentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    class: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    subject: [{
        subjectname: {
            type:String,
        },
        assessment: [{
            type: {
                type: String,
                require: true
            }, 
            score: {
                type: Array,
                require: true
            }, 
            total: {
                type: Array,
                require: true
            }, 
        }],
    }],  
    gendar: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },   
    birthday: {
        type: Date,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Students', StudentSchema);
```

I also have the code below in my route file;

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Student = require('../models/Student.js');


//GET BACK ALL THE STUDENTS
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const students = await Student.find();
            res.json(students);
    }   catch(err){
            res.json({message: err});
    }
});

//GET BACK ALL THE ASSESSMENT SCORE
router.get('/assessment/score', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const students = await Student.find({},{"subject.assessment.score":1});
            res.json(students);
    }   catch(err){
            res.json({message: err});
    }
});
...
...
// ADD A STUDENT
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const student = new Student({
        name: req.body.name,
        class: req.body.class,
        subject: [{
            subjectname: req.body.subjectname,
            assessment: [{
                type: req.body.type,
                score: req.body.score,
                total: req.body.total,
            }],
        }],
        gendar: req.body.gendar,
        birthday: req.body.birthday,
    });
    try{
    //console.log(req.body);
    const savedStudent = await student.save()
    res.json(savedStudent);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

The request in the above code works fine when tested with postman, but when I tried to update the score and total fields under assessment for a student, it does not work. below is the code I have tried so far;

```
//UPDATE A STUDENT ASSESSMENT
router.post('assessment/:studentId/:subjectId:/assessId', async (req, res) => {
    try{
    const updatedStudent = await Student.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.studentId }, 
        { "subject":{
            _id:req.params.subjectId,
            $push: { 
                "assessment": {
                    _id:req.params.assessId,
                    score: req.body.score,
                    total: req.body.total,
                },
            }  
        } }   
        );
        res.json(updatedStudent);
            }catch (err) {
                res.json({ message: err });
    }
});
```

In the code, I am trying to update the score and total using sub _ids of the various fields. I don't know if that is how to go about it. Any help to update the the score and total will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code for `Student.findByIdAndUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand you want to push a new assesment inside a specific subject inside a Student document( correct me if I am wrong ). Well you need to change the query selector a bit as well as the field you what to push into.

```
const updatedStudent = await Student.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.studentId, 'subject._id' : req.params.subjectId }, 
    { $push: { 
            "subject.$.assessment": {
                _id: req.params.assessId,
                score: req.body.score,
                total: req.body.total,
            },
        }  
    } }   
    );
    res.json(updatedStudent);
        }catch (err) {
            res.json({ message: err });
}
```

I think this way it should push a new assesment inside your subject in a Student doc ( not 100% percent sure, because I have not tried it ). But If you continue stuggle with this issue you might want to read some documentation about array update operators: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it did not work. Still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the code below to update the score, total and the type of assessment sub fields i the data;

```
router.post('/assessupdate_1/:studentId', async (req, res) => {
    try{
    const updatedAssessment = await Student.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.studentId }, 
        {$push: 
            {"subject.0.assessment.0.total":req.body.total,
            "subject.0.assessment.0.score":req.body.score,
            "subject.0.assessment.0.type":req.body.type,}
        },          
        );
        res.json(updatedAssessment);
            }catch (err) {
                res.json({ message: err });
    }
});
```